# reattach terminal tab to another window

Tags: terminal

Suppose you have a terminal with two tabs. You click, drag, and let go one of these tabs and it becomes an independent terminal window. After a while, you want to take this terminal window and reattach it as a tab to the previous window. How do you do it ? I have seen the merge windows option in the menus, but that merges *all* windows into one, which I would then have to revert.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You need to, in the window you want to move, go to View-> Show Tab Bar (if the tab bar isn't showing already).

Then, drag the tab of the window you want to move onto the window you want to move it to.

**Update for iTerm 2**: In iTerm 2 the setting is no longer exposed in the View menu.  Go to iTerm > Preferences > Appearance > Tabs and check "Show tab bar even when there is only one tab". Note that in early releases of iTerm 2 the setting was "Hide tab bar when there is only one tab".

[image: iTerm Screenshot]

Comment: For this and other reasons, I always have the tab bar visible. I recommend doing so, because tabs have several useful status/activity indicators (starting in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion).

Comment: I've tried Cmd+Shift+Option to click and drag iTerm2 tabs into other windows, but it only works with normal windows.  How can I merge tabs back into the Hotkey Window (I'm using iTerm2 in [visor](http://technosophos.com/content/configure-iterm2-act-visor) / [yakuake](http://yakuake.kde.org/)-like mode)

Comment: You can also Cmd+t to create a new tab and tab bar will automatically visible

Comment: It's called "Show toolbar" in my version.  The tab bar is always visible, but you cannot drag one tab into another window unless the *toolbar* is showing.

Comment: on the latest iterm2, showing one tab and dragging doesn't seem to work for me, so i need to do cmd+t to create a second tab.

Answer (score 35):

The answer is to hold down <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> whilst dragging the body of the terminal (not the tab) back to the terminal you wish to merge.

Source: http://azaleasays.com/2014/03/05/iterm2-merge-a-pane-back-to-window-or-tab-bar/

Comment: Note that this is for iTerm2 and _not_ for Terminal.

Comment: Also if you have multiple split panes in your tab, this moves each one individually rather than the whole tab in one go.

Comment: I'm glad Apple's products are so intuitive.

Comment: There is a youtube video on this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJzBd7GQlUo

Answer (score 10):

I have iTerm2 (Build 1.0.0.20130302) here - there's no `View` > `Show Tab Bar`. But as Chris Page suggested, disabling `Hide tab bar when there is only one tab` (in `Preferences` > `Appearance`) helps. The single windows can then be moved and merged again.

Comment: If you just have 1 tab and thus no tab bar, temporarily make a new tab, move away the tab you want, and then murder the temporary tab.

Comment: @DanJameson someone made an official answer from your post but I'm up-voting you 1) because it worked and 2) the use of the word `murder`

Answer (score 4):

You need to click and drag the tab from one window onto the tab bar of the other window to reattach it.

If either window has no tab bar because it is currently showing only one tab, <kbd>Command + T</kbd> to open a new tab, perform the action, then close any tabs you don't need. This works for both Terminal and iTerm2.

Full credit to *Dan Jameson* in the comments for this obvious solution.

Comment: simple & works great. life quality increase: priceless. thank you!

Comment: How can Apple break such a simple UX thing xD

Answer (score 3):

I had troubles merging windows with the [Hotkey Window](http://technosophos.com/content/configure-iterm2-act-visor) profile.  I eventually found a way to un-split the windows by doing the following:

1. `Preferences` > uncheck `Hide tab bar when there is only one tab`
2. Set `Tab position` to `Bottom`
3. Press your hotkey to show the Hotkey Window
4. Click & drag the tab into the Hotkey Window's tab bar

Comment: I just open another tab when I need to drag a tab into hotkey window.

Answer (score 2):

For Terminal (as opposed to Terminal2):

If the window you want to attach has just one tab (I.e. no tab bar) then add another tab. Then drag the tab of the one you want to the tab bar of the window you want to add it to.

I found it took a bit of jiggling before th image changed from an thumb nail of the window to just the tab.  This is the signal that your are in the right place!

It took me a while to realise I needed to add another tab but is is logical.

Comment: Thanks.  Adding another tab, to be able to drag from the tab bar, is what worked for me.  Really unintuitive from Apple :(